# how to remove extra space in android list alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to display sample alert dialog with single choice items and facing problem with
extra space after end of the list.

Here is my code

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(context, items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

[image: sample alert dialog with single choice items]

Suggest me to solve this.

Comment: I think the only way to do that is to create your dialog with your own custom dialog layout. Here is the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: See if you can get something from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761754/dialogfragment-with-extra-space-below-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your own dialog layout (see docs), but I'd suggest to leave it as is, as this dialog will look differently on HC/ICS/JB, so tweaking its look is quite bad idea as on other versions of android it may look different. It's just the way OS does it. Leave it is my advice.

Comment: As you said it will depend on OS i think why because i am not altering any property, just using default one. But i can't use this in my application as it's not looking good so, i created one custom dialog which satisfies my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing a similar issue when I had build the custom alert dialog.
In order to address the issue, I had to use theme to get rid of remaining spaces.
Following is the code that I had followed:

```
private Dialog getCustomDialog() {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Panel);
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialog.setView(dialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
      return dialog;
    }
```

As per the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_DeviceDefault_Panel) the usage of `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Panel` is followed:

> This removes all extraneous window decorations, so you basically have
>   an empty rectangle in which to place your content. It makes the window
>   floating, with a transparent background, and turns off dimming behind
>   the window.